# Calculus 2: Cylindrical Shells

Tags: calculus, integration

[image]

I have essentially tried using the integration formula for finding the volume of two different functions, which is pi times the integration of a to b of (R^2-r^2). In this case I used ((8-x^2)^2-(x^2)^2). However, I have struggled to determine the boundaries of the integral even though it is going to be rotated about the y-axis. Any assistance will be very helpful in my quest to conquer cylindrical shells. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Setting $ \ x^2  = 8 - x^2 \ , $ we find intersections  at $ \ x =  \pm 2 \ . $  The region being revolved is between an "upward-" and a "downward-opening" parabola, but only the section from $ \ x  =  1 \ $ to $ \ x = 2 \ . $  So the solid has a hollow interior with a cylindrical wall of radius 1 and an outer sloping surface that will form an "equatorial ridge".  The difference for the "shell method" is just $ \ (8 - x^2) - x^2 \ $, since you are taking "vertical slices", which are _parallel_ to the rotation axis.

Comment: For the shell method, you want the integral $ \ 2 \pi \ \int_1^2 \ x \ [(8 - x^2) - x^2] \ \ dx \ , $ as the integration of the "vertical shells" is carried out _perpendicular_ to the "vertical" rotation axis, the radius of a shell is the "horizontal distance" $ \ x \ $ from the $ \ y-$ axis, and the "height" of a shell is $ \ (8 - x^2) - x^2 \ . $

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formula for the cylindrical shells method (for a graph to rotate about an axis parallel to the $y$-axis is

$$\int_a^b2\pi*R(x)*H(x)\ dx$$

where $R$ is the radius of the cylindrical shell (varies with $x$) and $H$ is the height of the graph (which also varies with $x$)

Notice that the height of the cylindrical shell is $(8-x^2)-x^2$, because $8-x^2$ is larger than $x^2$ for $1 \leq x \leq 2$.

And revolving around the $y$-axis gives you a radius of $x$.

For cylindrical shells, the variable of integration is always opposite to what the axis of revolution is parallel to. In this case, the axis of revolution is the $y$-axis, hence the variable of integration is $x$.

Notice that the limits of integration are from $1$ to $2$.

So your integral should be

$$\int_1^2 2\pi x((8-x^2)-x^2)\ dx$$

I'm sure you can evaluate this yourself. :)

Comment: Thank you very much.This was an extremely helpful response, if I could I would vote up your answer, but sadly I do not have that power just yet. This will aid me in my studies for an upcoming exam and I appreciate how your detailed description.

Comment: If you didn't know, you can upvote any answer in a question that you asked regardless of your reputation count. :) I'm glad that it has helped you a fair bit! If you wish, I could include a cross-sectional method answer for this question, however that will take a little more of my time and for today, I don't think I can spare anymore so probably tomorrow? :) Cheers.